# Dual screens with one workspace on each?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I have a dual screen, compiz-fusion and i don't have a NVDIA/ATI graphic card and i use ubuntu 10.10.

i currently use the two monitors: the desktop is stretched across monitors and i can drag an application across monitors.

My question follows: i would like to use the left monitor only to display workspace1 and the right monitor to display workspace2. Is this possible ? If yes how (I've found mention of dualXscreen on this board, but i can't find it in the compizConfig menus).

Best,

Comment: You might like to take a look at [Fedora Dual Monitor - One Workspace Per Monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/29834/fedora-dual-monitor-one-workspace-per-monitor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Compiz doesn't support what you want.

I've heard that there are other window managers that can.  I don't remember which ones in particular -- Xmonad?  Awesome?  I remember that the one I heard about was a tiling window manager, and decided changing all my window-managing habits was too great a cost for this feature.

As a workaround I sometimes mark windows as visible on all workspaces and then keep them on one monitor.

Comment: In Awesome WM you have separate set of virtual desktops on each monitor.

Comment: +1 for the idea about visible in every workspace.  Never even noticed that option in the alt-click-right menu...